# mongo client error operation users find one buffering

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

hello I am using the mongo database and I want to save my files to the database but I keep getting this error [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaQ7x.png)

[image]

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database', {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(client => {
        console.log('Mongo Connected!!!');
        const db = client.db('database');
        const collection = db.collection('files');
        app.locals.fileCollection = collection;
    });
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problem -you're trying to query MongoDB before connection is established to the database.

Read - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering

> Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting
> for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB.

> That's because mongoose buffers model function calls internally. This buffering is convenient, but also a common source of confusion. Mongoose will not throw any errors by default if you use a model without connecting.

Solution - Wait for mongoose to connect before you start doing db queries.

Read - https://javascript.info/async-await